# How do I match "newline" in a DataTrigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, datatrigger

In my XAML, I am trying to implement the folowing:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Word}" Value="\n">
```

but this does not work, even though Word is \n.  I suspect that \n is not the right way to express newline in XAML, but what would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve the problem?

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Word}" Value="&#10;">
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works, you can try it:

```xml
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

```xml
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:Environment.NewLine}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: what happens if I'm matching to \n and Environment.Newline is \r\n?

Comment: Well, who creates your `word`? If that is internal you should always use `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: @tofutim: If you want more flexibility in terms of matching valid new-line strings you could employ a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

Comment: the user creates "word" and \r\n or \n could both be encountered, but you are right, i can probably find a way to force it to be Environment.Newline.

Answer (score 2):

After some testing, I found the answer is `&#010;`.